# Text in a template jumping to the left of the page. Why?

Tags: css

I have a template that I am modifying the text and pictures. It's all based on a 960grid, and the text is styled in external css sheets. When I copy one of the pieces of text (placed on the right of the site), and paste... it kicks the text to the left sidebar. What am I doing wrong? When I check the pasted text, it contains the same class, as the one that I copied from.

Thanks in advance.. I'm new to this and its giving me such a hard time!

Comment: Without more information, its hard to tell you what the problem is. Can you post a link or more information (example, code)?

Comment: I'm afraid nobody will be able to help you without you adding some code to your question. Please post the relevant parts of the HTML and the CSS.

Comment: You really haven't given us enough detail to answer this.

Comment: I agree, but I took a wack at it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is contained in something like a 'right sidebar' that actually places it on the right side of the page. Try making the division directly below where the division you copy ends.

```
<div class="right-sidebar">
    <div class="something">
    </div>
</div>
```

Into

```
<div class="right-sidebar">
    <div class="something">
    </div>
    <div class="something">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but i checked the class, and because i paste it, it has the same code as the text position that im trying to achieve..  here is what the code looks like:
<div class="grid_4">
     <h2 class="sifr-subtitle"> 2D Rendering </h2>
     <p>Miami-Dade Parking Garage - PGAL</p>
<p> <a class="button_visit" href="#home">Visit Site</a> <a class="button_next" href="#renderings">Next Item</a> </p>

is there an email that i can send my files to?  i really need the help.... thanks

Comment: Do you have a website you could link to? If so, link to it in a comment.

Comment: im having a tough time posting these to my site... cause its underconstruction..... can i have your email?

Comment: ok... here is the link to the files:
http://www.onlinefilefolder.com
username: info@pixel9studio.com
password: share

thanks!

Comment: You need to put it above the End Web Comment.

Comment: There is a comment that contains <!--- End Web Content -->.
You need to put your div above that.

Comment: sorry.. im a little confused here
... are you talking about the files i posted?

Comment: WELL.. i just wanted to thank you for trying to help me... i figured itout.... well sort of.  somehow, the text was not behaving properly when i used the same class from the original text that i wanted to imitate... so, i created a new class and changed the css properties of it.. so it has a padding , letting the text be placed on the right side of the site...  thank u so much again.

Comment: No problem. If you want to hit the Checkbox next to my answer, it would be appreciated. But not sure if you want to because I didn't actually give the answer. Glad to help.